# Create files in network shared drives

Tags: java, file, access-denied, network-drive

I want to create a file in Drive which is shared over the network.If I give normal path for file creation like :-

```
D:\\Folder\FileName.txt
```

this works but If I give

```
hostname\\Folder\Filename.txt
```

This gives me Access Denied Error.

1. Folder is shared to ALL/Everyone
2. I am using windows 7.

Comment: The path should be more like \\hostname\path\file, but I think you will find that Java will not see this as a valid File object.  You could try creating a URL to the oath, but this will depend on the protocol used to connect to the share (ie smb:// for samba shares)

Comment: There is no need to SHOUT at us.  :-/